# RGB 4 Code? 0, 255, 255, 197 (What is the last value)

Tags: python, colors, usb, reverse-engineering, rgb

i am reverse engineering a RGB LED Bias Light. These Values are getting send by my PC via USB to the device.
But i cant figure out the last part behind the rgb values.

Maybe some of you got an idea what it is and how to calculate it?
I dont think it is alpha channel

Samples:
The important part is behind the RGB values, below the 186, 218, 250, etc

If i am sending the same bytes as the software sends to the LEDs it works. But if i change the last value of the RGB-? it doesnt.

```
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 0, 255, 128, 186, 69, 68] 0, 255, 128
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 0, 255, 224, 218, 69, 68] 0, 255,224
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 0, 255, 192, 250, 69, 68] 0, 255, 192


[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 0, 255, 255, 197, 69, 68] 0,255,255
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 255, 0, 197, 69, 68] 255, 255, 0
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 255, 197, 69, 68] 255, 0, 255


[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 32, 0, 26, 69, 68]      255, 32, 0
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 32, 26, 69, 68]      255, 0, 32
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 64, 122, 69, 68]     255, 0, 64
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 128, 186, 69, 68]    255, 0, 128
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 160, 154, 69, 68]    255, 0, 160
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 192, 250, 69, 68]    255, 0, 192
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 224, 218, 69, 68]    255, 0, 224
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 255, 197, 69, 68]    255, 0, 255

[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 255, 0, 197, 69, 68]    255, 255, 0

[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 255, 58, 69, 68] 0, 0, 255
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 0, 255, 0, 58, 69, 68] 0, 255, 0
[83, 67, 210, 2, 4, 1, 255, 0, 0, 58, 69, 68] 255, 0, 0
```

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: You should try different settings. I assume that one is white. You may want to look Arduino libraries which may already have the reverse engineered value for your devices.

Comment: as @GiacomoCatenazzi said, it's most likely a RGB+W representation.

Comment: What does "white" mean in RGB+W? The white color is `255,255,255` in RGB.

Comment: There are LED lights with an extra white LED so you get a better white.
In my case, the last variable is probably not white, because it changes depending on RGB.
I've been trying to figure out how to calculate this for ages. It seems that the value is always subtracted and as soon as it reaches 0 it starts again at 128.
In the half, however, this reverses.
So no idea what this is

Comment: Could you explain what those numbers are that you are showing to us?  It looks like an array of 12 bytes, following by a list of 3 numbers.  Am I right in guess that the 3 numbers are the RGB value you are trying to send, and the list of 12 bytes is the command that the software sends to your hardware device?  What is `vergleich`? 
 Don't make us reverse engineer your post when we should be reverse engineering the device.

Comment: It's probably not a CRC because swapping RGB bytes never effects the fourth byte.  Could you try every color of the form [0,0, i], where i is between 0 and 255?  Or maybe just trying i = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128] would be enough to see a pattern.

Comment: I cant set 0, 0, 255.
The Software doesnt let me to do this.
But i know the LED can do it because i already found one fourth byte for a combination by bruteforcing

Comment: But i updated the values in the description